# Create a dictionary of letters and their associated count

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I create of letter and their associated count from a string? By creating a dictionary from the string? in Jupyter Hub

peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers;
a peck of pickled peppers peter picked;
if peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers,
where's the peck of pickled peppers peter picked?

Comment: `collections.Counter(my_string)`

Comment: I don't think this should be tagged with `python-requests`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Counter`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/collection/python-collections-counter):

```
from collections import Counter
t_str = "peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers; a peck of pickled peppers peter picked; if peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers, where's the peck of pickled peppers peter picked?"
print(Counter(t_str))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Counter({'e': 33, 'p': 32, ' ': 31, 'c': 12, 'k': 12, 'r': 11, 'i': 11, 'd': 8, 't': 5, 'f': 5, 's': 5, 'o': 4, 'l': 4, 'a': 3, ';': 2, 'h': 2, ',': 1, 'w': 1, "'": 1, '?': 1})
```

**OR**

```
print(dict((letter,t_str.count(letter)) for letter in set(t_str)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'?': 1, ',': 1, 'r': 11, 'p': 32, ' ': 31, 'k': 12, 'a': 3, 'l': 4, 'd': 8, 'h': 2, "'": 1, 'i': 11, 'w': 1, 'c': 12, ';': 2, 't': 5, 'o': 4, 's': 5, 'f': 5, 'e': 33}
```

**EDIT** (to count the occurrence of letters from `a-z`, regardless of their existence in the string i.e it would be equal to `0` in that case):

```
import string
letter_set = string.ascii_lowercase

print(dict((letter,t_str.count(letter)) for letter in letter_set))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': 12, 'd': 8, 'e': 33, 'f': 5, 'g': 0, 'h': 2, 'i': 11, 'j': 0, 'k': 12, 'l': 4, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 4, 'p': 32, 'q': 0, 'r': 11, 's': 5, 't': 5, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 1, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Comment: Just to add, if you do  import string ; letter_set = string.ascii_lowercase; you can replace set(t_str) with letter_set to only get letters and ignore symbols.

Comment: @dijksterhuis Indeed, added. Thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you both very much!! I'm not good at programming what so ever thanks again!!

Comment: @D.Chesney, you're welcome, you may consider accepting the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers